# Google App Engine "Error [13] An internal error occurred" when deploying Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I recently began seeing this error when deploying symfony 2.6.11 to Google App Engine:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred
```

In case anyone else sees this, I wanted to post my solution here.  I deleted the following file:

```
vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Finder/Tests/Fixtures/r+e.gex\[c\]a\(r\)s/dir/bar.dat
```

And now the app deploys just fine. This is a test fixtures file, so it's okay to ignore. I suggest updating app.yaml to ignore this file using the [skip_files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Skipping_files) parameter:

```
skip_files:
  - (.*/)?Tests\/Fixtures\/(.*)
```

**NOTE**: I assume this is only breaking for the bleeding-edge deployment of `gcloud`, and will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned above, the solution is to add the `skip_files` directive to your App Engine `app.yaml`